# How to code this json in android

Tags: java, json

hi I am new in this forum I am trying the following in Android studio, I need to create a `json` object with this format

```
    {
      "enviaya_account": "Y0DCRGIU",
      "carrier_account": null,
      "api_key":"YOUR_API_KEY",
        "shipment":{
          "shipment_type":"Package",
          "parcels":[
            {
              "quantity":"1",
              "weight":"3",
              "weight_unit":"kg",
              "length":"10",
              "height":"20",
              "width":"30",
              "dimension_unit":"cm"
            }
          ]
        },
        "origin_direction":{
          "country_code":"MX",
          "postal_code":"11550"
        },
        "destination_direction":{
          "country_code":"MX",
          "postal_code":"01210"
        },
        "insured_value":"5000",
        }

"insured_value_currency":"MXN"
}
```

but I can not integrate it well since it marks me errors could someone help me please? the code that I have is this:

```
JSONObject Request = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject shipment = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray parcels = new JSONArray();
        JSONObject parcel= new JSONObject();
        JSONObject origin_direction = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject destination_direction = new JSONObject();


        try {
            Request.put("enviaya_account","Y0DCRGIU");
            Request.put("carrier_account","");
            Request.put("api_key","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            shipment.put("shipment_type","package");
            Request.put("shipment",shipment);
            parcel.put("quantity","1");
            parcel.put("weight","10.98");
            parcel.put("weight_unit","kg");
            parcel.put("length","39");
            parcel.put("height","39");
            parcel.put("width","29");
            parcel.put("dimension_unit","cm");
            parcels.put(parcel);
            Request.put("parcels",parcels);
            origin_direction.put("country_code","MX");
            origin_direction.put("postal_code","29267");
            destination_direction.put("country_code","MX");
            destination_direction.put("postal_code","34200");
            Request.put("origin_direction",origin_direction);
            Request.put("destination_direction",destination_direction);
            Request.put("insured_value","0");
            Request.put("insured_value_currency","MXN");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        edt.setText(Request.toString());
```

but when I try to check it in POSTMAN it tells me that the parcels object does not exist

[image]

Comment: wellcome to stack ..post the error logs

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know since "parcels" is defined as a JSONArray object, you need to call add method.

```
parcels.put(parcel); 
// should instead be 
parcels.add(parcel);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code of some part.

```
 JSONObject Request = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject shipment = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray parcels = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject parcel= new JSONObject();
    JSONObject origin_direction = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject destination_direction = new JSONObject();


    try {
        Request.put("enviaya_account","Y0DCRGIU");
        Request.put("carrier_account","");
        Request.put("api_key","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        shipment.put("shipment_type","package");
        parcel.put("quantity","1");
        parcel.put("weight","10.98");
        parcel.put("weight_unit","kg");
        parcel.put("length","39");
        parcel.put("height","39");
        parcel.put("width","29");
        parcel.put("dimension_unit","cm");
        parcels.put(parcel);
        shipment.put("parcels",parcels);
        Request.put("shipment",shipment);
        origin_direction.put("country_code","MX");
        origin_direction.put("postal_code","29267");
        destination_direction.put("country_code","MX");
        destination_direction.put("postal_code","34200");
        Request.put("origin_direction",origin_direction);
        Request.put("destination_direction",destination_direction);
        Request.put("insured_value","0");
        Request.put("insured_value_currency","MXN");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Json value", String.valueOf(Request));
```

this give me result like below screen shot.[image]